# How to extrude and scale with an even offset?

Tags: mesh

I'm quite new to Blender, so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I don't even know hot to describe it properly, so:

[image: What I want]

[image: What I get]

Basically I want to extrude a rectangle and then scale it along two axis, but without keeping the proportions; I want to reduce them of the same quantity, so that I get something similar to the frame of a picture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [***"Inset"***](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) is *a* method to do this.

Select the face to "extrude", then press <kbd>I</kbd> to *inset*.

You can then inset a face almost like extruding and scaling, but evenly.

[image]

The *inset* tool is also useful for many other things, but this is one of its benefits.

*Note: If you have a face that you would like to add a frame to, select the face then press* <kbd>I</kbd>. *You do not need to delete the face or anything. The "inset" tool is designed to inset :P*

Comment: @UnlceSnail the tool is **"inset"** not "insert"

Comment: The inset tool is also good to add a border around [odd shapes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21120/935)

Answer (score 7):

What you want is the *Inset* operator in *Edit Mode*. Select a face (or a bunch of faces) and press <kbd>i</kbd>, adjust the distance with the mouse or type the desired value on the keyboard.

Have in mind that for the inset to remain even with equal distances your object must have applied scale. In *Object Mode* select your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale* before insetting