# How to scale Faces evenly?

Tags: modeling, workflow, faces, extrude

Here I have created a rectangularly-shaped object.

- I applied the scale using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then selected the bottom face.
- I press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, tap enter and then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale.
- I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the face only on the X and Y axis

It doesn't scale evenly (see below):
[image]

I have no idea how to get around this problem. Is there a way to scale it evenly, sort of like a reverse inset function?

Comment: possible duplicated? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52308/19287

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I want to scale it to be bigger, while keeping the shape even.

Comment: When u scale press alt+s

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the "Inset" tool. This tool has an "Outset" option which works for your situation.

- First select the face
- Press <kbd>I</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Either press <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the operator settings or go to the Tool Shelf (if it's not visible bring it up using <kbd>T</kbd>)
- Check the `Outset` option.
- In the operator settings, increase the `Depth` as desired.

[image: Outset option]

**Update**

If you don't want the height to change, simply set the snap element to "Vertex" and move the face in the z-axis while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Much closer to what I wanted, but I don't wish for the height from where it is scaled to change.

Comment: @EmeraldEelEntertainment You can simply move the extruded face in the z-axis and snap it to one of the vertices

Comment: I think I figured it out (at least for this kind of model). I changed the snap settings to increment and made sure that absolute grid alignment was enabled; I then shifted it to where the original extrude point was, then extruded down to add the base.

Comment: @EmeraldEelEntertainment, snapping to grid _may_ _not_ always work. It's better to snap to vertex. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hm, I could have sworn I used that option. I will take this into account the next time.