# Why can't I scale the mesh?

Tags: modifiers, scale

I have 2 meshes and I added a 3mm solidify modifier to both of them. The upper red mesh looks merged to me, so I want to scale it a little so that I can't see the red mesh from black.

In the edit mode I select all the meshes and press Alt+s to scale it a little. It's going up or down, but I can't scale little to make it smaller. I applied scale and rotation to both yet to same result. Does anyone have any suggestions or help on how to make it work?

[image]

[image: gif showing the error]

Comment: I think you're looking for the Inset tool. Similar issue at: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/how-to-extrude-and-scale-with-an-even-offset

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand try just pressing s + x/z/y instead of alt s. Also make sure proportional editing is off