# Equal Extrusions?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to extrude this so all edges are equal distance from their origin edges?

[image]

But when I extrude and size them it turns out like this.

[image]

How can I get them equal distance apart?

[image]

When I change the Offset it doesn't extrude like yours is? Mine goes to the side?

Comment: [Using inset may help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21120/935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *Extrude Along Vetex Normals* on the side faces.
It requires a bit of cleanup afterwards

1. Delete the top faces
2. Extrude side faces along vertex normals normals <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
3. Delete extra faces
4. Bridge the two remaining edgeloops with *Bridge Edge Loops*

[image: Extrude vertex normals]s

**EDIT** Make sure your your mesh is uniformly scaled on all axis, and you have applied scale to the object, otherwise the operation will still be deformed.
Use the operator panel to the left of the 3D screen to introduce accurate distances

[image: Extrude vertex normals]

Comment: How did you select the faces like that?

Comment: It's the "loop select" operator, by default Alt + Rightmouse button

Comment: When I push Alt +E it just expands it outward I cant get it to size?

Comment: Yes, just check the tool shelf to the bottom left of the 3D view, there will appear an operator panel afterwards with options. You can specify accurate distances there

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that? Do I Alt+E and then select that option? I don't know what you mean by the "operator panel"?

Comment: Check the new image I added above to the answer. after you execute extrude normals a panel will appear to the left of the 3D view with options to control the extrusion. There you can enter any value you want

Comment: @Muly options can be tweaked right after that, you can also see it by hitting F6.

Comment: I edited my post as well. When I do the Alt+E it extrudes to the side weirdly?

Comment: I fixed it x.x I need to select origin point when extruding it. Thanks a lot!