# Extrude Individual Faces (Corners) and Expand Without Scaling

Tags: extrude

Was hoping someone could help me out with this predicament.
I am currently making a video game within unity and most of the environment will be made of square tiles.

After having a frame composed of 4 rectangles, I want to extrude outwards to create the following object:

[image]

Only problem is that I would like the corner(black arrow) to be filled in with another square. Other methods are able to fill in the corner but not with square faces like I desire. For instance, a normal extrude will create an edge diagonal to the corner vertex.

Second problem I am running into...Is there a way to expand this frame while retaining the original scale. For example, transform this frame to the first.

[image]

Bonus Question:

I am fairly new to the whole unity and blender scene. Would it be more extensive on the game to tile game objects made in blender with faces or with materials made in unity. For example, in blender: have a 5x5 tile (25 faces) and apply a 1x1 material to each face of the object or have a 5x5 tile (1 face) and apply a 5x5 material to the face. Of course the first condition would increase the number of vertices greatly while the second condition would require my project to have 100's of materials but only applying 1 material per object.

I apologize for the poor wording in my questions. Have been confusing myself as well.

Thank you for any sort of help!

Comment: Please post different questions rather than one mega one.

Comment: Check the solution here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56693/equal-extrusions/56694#56694 or try using a solidify modifier

Comment: Duarte, I appreciate the suggestion. With that solution it causes the empty corner like I previously described above. With the solidify, it causes an angled edge going from inner corner to outer corner. I was hoping for cube in that corner...or square faces to put it simply.

Comment: If the corners are empty it probably means your edges are disconnected, try removing duplicate geometry with **W** > *Remove Doubles* before adding thickness. As for the solidify modifier try the option *Even Thickness*

Comment: Regarding the texturing question, there will be no significant difference if you use 25 small texture files or one big one (in the case you specified), other than the slight increase in vertices. If you can keep all the textures for each face in one file, you might as well. The thing you want to avoid is having unused texture areas in the image files.