# Extruding surface while keeping the shape

Tags: modeling

[image]here is the picture of what I would like to get(example nr. 2). I need the edge frame to be same in width and length. Also the extrusion is on surface (without depth) I tried extruding region, but it did not give me the result I wanted. 
 I know I could just adjust the scale and do it manually, but that would be eyeballing without achievign accuracy. I would like to know if it is possible to extrude or inset while keeping the shape (even edge space)

Comment: Related -http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21107/can-shapes-with-rounded-corners-be-extruded-with-even-thickness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Inset the face

1. Go into edit mode. Select the face. *right-click*
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the face.

OR

2. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* menu.
3. From the *Specials* menu, choose **Inset Faces**. <kbd>I</kbd>

OR

2. Press<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the *Faces* menu.
3. From the *Faces* menu, choose **Inset Faces**. <kbd>I</kbd>

OR

2. Choose *Mesh > Faces > Inset Faces* from the edit mode menu.

[image: Faces]

Answer (score 0):

With the object selected in Object Mode. Press "Ctrl+A" and click "Scale" to apply the any scaling operations you performed in Object Mode. Now in Edit Mode, select the plane and press "I" to inset it.