# Adding Edge Loops Around Airplane Window

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, bmesh

I would like to add an edge loop around each one of these windows and are not 100% sure on the best way to do it even after watching some videos.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21107/935)

Answer (score 5):

Avoid NGons, and avoid Boolean operations, you topology is not quad-dominant and you wont be able to easily add edgeloops anywhere with ngons like those around the windows. in fact you will likely have a hard time doing anything at all with your current model.

Ideally your mesh should be made primarily of faces with four sides, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add edge loops, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, use <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, and abuse of modifiers.

In your case I am guessing a *Mirror* modifier would help with symmetry, a *Subdivision Surface* would help with smoothing/curving, and an array might help with multiple windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can select the faces and just use  <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the selection, this will add loops to arbitrary geometry in a way the is relatively even.