# Boolean Modifier in Blender 2.8 not working as I expect to

Tags: modifiers

I am relatively new to the community and the internet couldn't help me this time.

I am creating an airplane model and want to cut out the windows and doors from the basic shape. But as soon as the boolean is not at the edge of one of the side the boolean does not work as I expect to work it.[image: As you can see the Door and Window are like extruded inwards whereas the cube below is correctly cut out from the mesh.]

I hope you can help me somehow to get it work. If you need it I can post the file.

Regards OupsyDoupsy

[As Requested here the file:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tyi9e7dtPHOTthsNWkPDmftaJHC3coj1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Edge Loops Around Airplane Window](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/adding-edge-loops-around-airplane-window)

Comment: Please add a blender file if possible. Are you sure that the Boolean is on difference?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you for that link. It is right that way I would have liked to do it but as there are a lot of windows and I have some other parts of the aircraft within this mesh it is very complicated to find a way to do it so that the subsurf works well. But thank you for that link, I will for sure look at it if there is really to alternative as remeshing the whole thing again.

Comment: @caleblee the file is now attached