# How do I hollow a 3D model in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and barely know it's features. I am working on a game and I have to make flying airplanes for it.  I want to hollow the fuselage of the plane so that I can make the interior of the plane. I am using YouTube tutorials for the time being, but I haven't found one where the fuselage gets hollowed. I will also need to make plane windows, I think it has to do with the main title of the post. Can you guys help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can hide selected elements using H key and make it reappear using Alt+H.

Comment: The game is going to be for Roblox, and that's why I'm going to make a Roblox reference - can I duplicate the cylinder and make the duplicate a negative part, then make a union with those 2 or something like that?

Comment: Yes you can also separate the cylinder part (select it and P to separate). Once the modification done, join them back (select both objects and Ctrl+J)

Comment: Ok, but can I make the duplicate a negative part?

Comment: What do you mean by negative? Inverting normals?

Comment: I don't know how it's called in blender, but what I'm thinking is a part that digs a hole into the model

Comment: I don't know how the model is done (no picture in your question), but I think the easiest way is to hide the part you don't want to see (as said in first comment)

Comment: Do you maybe want what the "solidify modifier" does?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object/50254 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/adding-edge-loops-around-airplane-window/81222

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Solidify Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html). It adds thickness to you polygons. Simply make windows holes into your fuselage and then use solidify modifier and you will have hollow fuselage with windows.