# Boolean weird lines after applied

Tags: boolean-modifier

I used the boolean modifier to create spaces for wheels on the truck i am working on and after i apply it there are these weird lines that do not show in edit mode. How could i fix this?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what weird lines? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I shared it. The lines are near the edges where the boolean cuts out the piece. Thanks

Comment: Boolean often creates bad topology, you need to apply the modifier and correct manually

Comment: Avoid Booleans, use [proper topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/adding-edge-loops-around-airplane-window)