# How to Extrude so That Extruded Face Isn't Parallel

Tags: objects, extrude

I just had a quick quick question.  So in the image, you can see that when I extrude from an edge loop, the extruded edge that comes out of it is always parallel to the original edge loop that I extruded from.  How do I extrude so that the angle of the extruded edge loop isn't parallel to the original ie) it follows the door.  I know there is a way of doing this without creating curves and beveling.  Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21120/935)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a newly-converted fan of the Offset Edges plugin.  It does exactly what you're describing (I think, based on your description).

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges

Edit: it does this type of thing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your faces selected, hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and find: 'Extrude Region and Shrink/Fatten'

[image]

You can't extrude too far in or you will have to clean the top up a bit.

You can, however, go about this backwards, too, using inset.

Model the inner radius first.

[image]

Extrude below the floor so inset doesn't mess with the lower end of your mesh.

[image]

Select the front and hit <kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

After that, repair the damage.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice option to know about but it does not, in my experience, do a reliable inset/outset . .. occasionally it looks right, often it does not.  It all depends on what you're looking for I guess.

Comment: Some topology doesn't like that tool, true. But I built an arch like the one in the picture and it behaved, so I thought it belongs in here.

Comment: Absolutely, it does belong here, it is a good solution in certain cases!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I ended up manually going in and rotating each loop to go around but those other answers are really useful as well:)

Comment: To clarify a bit, since the answer was edited subsequent to my comment: shrink/fatten does work fairly reliably on faces.  The modified answer shows how to use it in this fashion.  However, it does not work reliably on edges, which is what the question concerned.  The Offset Edges plugin works on edges without having to locate or create faces with normals pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I have the nasty habit of iterating my answers. I admit that I didn't think of it as an edge problem because the intended result was probably a watertight mesh again.